# How to place my audit file in Amazon S3?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have installed and configured the `auditd` package in Amazon Ec2 instance. I wish I need to place all the auditd log files in Amazon S3.

I'm very new to Ubuntu can anyone explain me how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use s3cmd via cron to periodically copy logs up to an s3 bucket.